# Is it possible to upload a Revit file to a web app and implement Dynamo code on it? Like implement Dynamo code on Revit file outside of Revit

Tags: python, autodesk-forge, revit-api

I am new to Autodesk Revit API and Forge API development. Doing a small project with/for my students. I am trying to read a Revit file using python (or upload it to a web app) and implement a custom Dynamo code on that Revit file. I explored Revit-API, Autodesk Forge and few other online resources but I couldn't find what I was looking for. Could please someone advise if it is possible to read a Revit file and apply Dynamo code to it outside of Revit? If yes, please point me towards right resources. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Revit and Forge API development.

Basically, the answer is No.

Currently, to work on a Revit file with Dynamo, you need to do so on the Windows desktop with an open Revit session running.

The only way to execute Revit API code without a running Windows desktop Revit session open is
via [Forge Design Automation for Revit](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/overview).

Unfortunately, Forge currently does not support any Dynamo.

Comment: Thank you so much Jeremy! My Dynamo code extracts certain data (area, dimensions, coordinates, centroids etc) from the Revit file and saves them to text files. Is it possible to convert this Dynamo code to any other programming language or is there any other way to extract such information from Revit file without using Dynamo? Please advise. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, absolutely. You can convert it to any language supporting the .NET framework, cf. the [Revit API development requirements](https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2021/ENU/?guid=Revit_API_Revit_API_Developers_Guide_Introduction_Getting_Started_html). For simplicity and optimal support, I would recommend using C#. Once you have implemented a C# .NET Revit add-in on the Windows desktop, you can easily [convert it to DA4R](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.55).

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate your help. I will explore your suggested solution.